# How to add webcam feed to my webpage

Tags: php, jquery

its me again.. is it possible to take webcam stream and add it to webpage? I checked page source. looks like it creates image in folder on their server 
(http://www2.hak.hr/rmt/?l=135) is it posible to get that image to my webpage? Thanks anyone for help

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Stack Overflow != Google. A simple search yields your answer.

Comment: If you just need the webcam feed, create a simple app in flash and embed the swf in your website. there will be no need to create a folder unless you want to stream and record the feed onto a server.

Comment: sorry..i didnt manage to find something that is similar. usualy its about personal webcams..with local folder or something.. ok.. will try to search more. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed the image with something like this:

```
<img src="http://www2.hak.hr/hak_webcam/cam.asp?id=22" alt="img"></img>
```

You just have one problem when the image adress is changing you have to do it too! To prevent the embed from another site it seems like they are adding as url parameter a timestamp.

As you can see they have a copyright on this so you aren't allowed to embed it.

Comment: omg what an idiot i am.. i did that.. but image didnt show to me.. because i left out http looks like.. now it displays. i think id stays the same.. so i think this could work..im so sorry for this mistake... if its possible admin can delete thread.. thanks m8

Comment: @Emanuel When this was the solution please mark the answer as correct. I am glad i could help :)